# Color Change not showing in Element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a grid working so that I can use it as a canvas. However, when I try to change the color of the elements(as a test), nothing shows up. However, when I give the class a dotted border(doesn't work with solid, it just turns black) the color I am trying to change to works. However, if I remove the border then the color goes away as well.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

     4/28/15


     Graph Part 2
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>this will appear on the tab in the browser</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="graph.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
*{border: 0;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}
body
{
margin:0;border:0;padding:0;
font-family:"Times New Roman";
font-size: 12pt;
}
#header
{
    width: 36em;
    height: 3em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#left
{
    height: 21em;
    width: 7em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: -223px;
}
#area
{
    height: 21em;
    width: 21em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -338px;
    left: 2px;

}
#right
{
    height: 21em;
    width: 7em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -677px;
    left: 228px;
}
#sketch
{
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 3em;

}
#small_box
{
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: -57px;
    left: 458px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.box{border: 1px solid;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">
<div id="sketch">Click a Sketch
<div id="small_box"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="area"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var array;
    var count;
    var html;
    var i;
    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    array = new Array(4);
    array[0] = getRandomRGB();
    array[1] = getRandomRGB();
    array[2] = getRandomRGB();
    array[3] = getRandomRGB();
    document.getElementById("small_box").style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
    createColorChoice(array, "left", "palette", updateCurrentColor);
    createColorChoice(array, "right", "canvas", updateCanvasColor);
    html = createDrawingArea("grid", 20, 30, "box", "startofRow");
    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = html;
    count = countElementsWithIdPrefixOf("grid");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("grid" + i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
function colorTheBox(prefix, color)
{
    this.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("small_box").style.backgroundColor;
}
function createDrawingArea(prefix, rows, columns, classId, start)
{
    var classInfo;
    var count;
    var html;
    var i;
    var j;

    html = "";
    count = 0;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
    {
        classInfo = classId + " " + start;
        j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j = j + 1)
        {
            html = html + createHTMLElement("div", prefix + count, classInfo, "");
            count = count + 1;
            j = j + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return html;
}
function setColorChoice()
{
    var prompt;
    prompt = window.prompt("Enter a color: ")
    if (prompt.length > 0)
    {
        this.style.backgroundColor = prompt;
    }
}
function updateCanvasColor() {
    document.getElementById("area").style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
}
function updateCurrentColor()
{
    document.getElementById("small_box").style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
}
function createColorChoice(array, containerId, palettePrefix, reference)
{
    var containerHeight;
    var containerWidth;
    var i;
    var newHtml;
    i = 0;
    newHtml = "";
    containerId = "" + containerId;
    palettePrefix = "" + palettePrefix;
    containerHeight = document.getElementById(containerId).offsetHeight;
    containerWidth = document.getElementById(containerId).offsetWidth;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        newHtml = newHtml + createHTMLElement("div", palettePrefix + i, "", "");
        document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML = newHtml;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.height = "3em"; 
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.width = "3em";
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.border = "1px solid black";
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.marginLeft = "auto";
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.marginRight = "auto";
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.marginTop = "10px";
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.marginBottom = "5px";
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).style.backgroundColor = array[i];
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).onmouseover = reference;
        document.getElementById(palettePrefix + i).onclick = setColorChoice;
    }
}
function getCurrentColor(id)
{
    var element;
    element = document.getElementById(id)
    return element.style.backgroundColor
}
function countElementsWithIdPrefixOf(prefix)
{
    var count;
    var i;
    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (document.getElementById(prefix + i) !== null)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
function getRandomRGB() // Uses getRandomInteger to generate random RGB colors.
{
    var red;
    var green;
    var blue;
    var result;
    red = getRandomInteger(255);
    green = getRandomInteger(255);
    blue = getRandomInteger(255);
    result = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
    return result;

}
function getRandomInteger(upperLimit) // Gets a random number on less than upperLimit
{
    var result;
    result = Math.random();
    result = result * (upperLimit + 1);
    result = Math.floor(result);




    return result;
}
function createHTMLElement(elementType, id, classInfo, content) {
    if (elementType == null) {
        elementType = "";
    }
    if (id == null) {
        id = "";
    }
    if (classInfo == null) {
        classInfo = "";
    }
    if (content == null) {
        content = "";
    }
    else {
        elementType = "" + trim(elementType);
        id = ' id = ' + '"' + trim(id) + '"';
        classInfo = ' class = ' + '"' + trim(classInfo) + '"';
        content = "" + trim(content);
    }
    return "<" + elementType + id + classInfo + ">" + content + "</" + elementType + ">"; // returns a properly formatted html statement.
}
function trim(data) //trim function that removes all the whitespace from a string.
{
    var result;
    var whitespace;
    var start;

    if (typeof data === "string") {
        whitespace = " \n\r\t\f";
        start = 0;

        while (start < data.length && whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(start)) > -1) {
            start = start + 1;
        }

        var end;
        end = data.length - 1;

        while (end >= 0 && whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(end)) > -1) {
            end = end - 1;
        }

        if (end < start) {
            result = "";
        }
        else {
            result = data.substring(start, end + 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        result = data;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is where the issue is(I believe):

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  document.getElementById("grid" + i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: I suspect putting something inside your `div`s may help - try including a `&nbsp;`

Comment: I was just going to say that! Divs like a bit of content for some reason

Comment: It works, but it goes completely outside of the allotted area. How can this be fixed? Is there something wrong with my createDrawingArea function? It also breaks the functionality of the right side of the colors. When you mouseover those the area in the middle is supposed to have its color changed to whatever is on the right side.

Comment: Can you jsfiddle this? I deleted my answer, I didn't get correctly the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add content or you can set the width and height

```
.box{border: 1px solid; display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px;}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ocmguzwx/) in action